# how do we set the content type header for a local file?

Tags: javascript, file, local, local-files

how do we set the content type header for a page not served from a server? (i.e. a simple local file saved to desktop)

Say i have a .xml file that i would like to open as `application/xml` in google-chrome. how do i specify it?

Now i want to open that same file under `text/xml` with google-chrome is that an option?

My file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test></test>
```

Comment: Open how? Can you show some example code?

Comment: You're still not saying *how* you are planning to open the file? Using a program? Using scripting? On the operating system's shell or desktop? For what purpose?

Comment: @Pekka i don't get you.. i mean i'd double click it to open in my browser?

Comment: @Pacerier sorry, I misread your post. I understand now. No, this is not possible - browsers will automatically interpret the content type from the file's extension. There is no way to force a different MIME type for local files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't.  HTTP header exists only if it's a HTTP request or response.  AFAIK, you can't set more than 1 association to a single file type in your web browser.

Answer (score 6):

Headers are only sent to and served by servers. Without a server, there is no such thing as a request, or a response, and therefore there will be no content-type header to receive.

If you are trying to keep this local, you can open it on a localhost server setup. IIS and Apache (and many others) will run on your local development box, no problem.

Comment: no i do not mean the localhost server.. i mean the local file system. so its just impossible?

Comment: That's correct. There's no server when you open it from the local file system. It's just a file.